# Exclude services from starting with docker-compose

Tags: docker-compose

**Use Case**

The `docker-compose.yml` defines multiple services which represent the full application stack. In development mode, we'd like to dynamically exclude certain services, so that we can run them from an IDE.

As of Docker compose 1.28 it is possible to assign profiles to services [as documented here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/profiles/) but as far as I have understood, it only allows specifying which services shall be started, not which ones shall be excluded.

Another way I could imagine is to split "excludable" services into their own `docker-compose.yml` file but all of this seems kind of tedious to me.

Do you have a better way to exclude services?

Comment: I believe you listed all options. Why don't you like profiles? You can create a profile that start containers without excluded ones and another profile that would start everything there is (that is 'no profile' I think). It seems more flexible to me than excluding, although a bit more code in your case.

Comment: Maybe I didn't completey get the idea of profiles, but let's say I have ten services in the `docker-compose.yml` where one is called `backend` and one `frontend`. When wanting to develop the `backend` service, then I would need to assign a `no-backend` profile to the `frontend` service and vice versa? If the number of services grows, then this sounds like a lot of verbose profile names?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems we both overlooked a certain very important thing about profiles and that is:

> Services without a `profiles` attribute will *always* be enabled

So if you run `docker-compose up` with a file like this:

```yaml
version: "3.9"
services:
  database:
    image: debian:buster
    command: echo database

  frontend:
    image: debian:buster
    command: echo frontend
    profiles: ['frontend']

  backend:
    image: debian:buster
    command: echo backend
    profiles: ['backend']
```

It will start the `database` container only. If you run it with `docker-compose --profile backend up` it will bring `database` and `backend` containers. To start everything you need to `docker-compose --profile backend --profile frontend up` or use a single profile but several times.

That seems to me as the best way to make `docker-compose` not to run certain containers. You just need to mark them with a profile and it's done. I suggest you give the [profiles reference](https://docs.docker.com/compose/profiles/) a second chance as well. Apart from some good examples it explains how the feature interacts with service dependencies.